# How to create a fading mask in html5 canvas for a white background

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, radial-gradients

I got a circular canvas animation and I want to fade out the edges. The solution I ended up with was to create a larger canvas to put in front with a radial gradient from transparent to whatever color the background is. This works great for a black background, but I cannot figure out why I get a gray gradient when I make it [white](http://jsfiddle.net/elpadi/4XGN7/2/).

```
var c = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = c.getContext('2d'),
    w = 300,
    w2 = w / 2,
    h = 300,
    h2 = h / 2,
    cr = 100
;

c.width = w;
c.height = h;
ctx.rect(0, 0, w, h);
var g = ctx.createRadialGradient(
    w2,
    h2,
    1,
    w2,
    h2,
    cr * 90 / 100
);
g.addColorStop(0, 'transparent');
g.addColorStop(1, '#ffffff');
ctx.fillStyle = g;
ctx.fill();
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4XGN7/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be ignoring the fact that "transparent" *has* a colour. Transparent maps to rgba(0,0,0,0), which is invisible black. When you transition from invisible black to visible white, in the middle you'll get transparent grey.

Therefore, you can just replace

```
g.addColorStop(0, 'transparent');
```

with

```
g.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(255,255,255,0)');
```

Which is invisible white.